# Binding a StaticResource to a FrameworkElement's property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to use Petzold's LineChartGenerator (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291567.aspx) which is accessed as a StaticResource:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <src:CensusData x:Key="censusData" />
    <charts:LineChartGenerator 
            x:Key="generator"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource censusData}}"
            Width="300"
            Height="200">
        </charts:LineChartGenerator.VerticalAxis>
    </charts:LineChartGenerator>
</Window.Resources>
```

but I'd like to bind the width and height to the current width and height of a control. Shouldn't this be:

```
 <charts:LineChartGenerator 
            x:Key="generator"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource censusData}}"
            Width="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=Width}"
            Height="200">
```

but this gives me a binding error: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Width; DataItem=null; target element is 'LineChartGenerator' (HashCode=52313994); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Is it possible to do this? I have various kludges but they all set the width of teh control to the width of the LineChartGenerator which really isn't the desired effect!

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I believe that since you width property is in the Window.Resources tag the width binding should look something like this...

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```